# Progress Indicator when firebase is retrieving data on chat - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a flutter project chat with firebase realtime database and when I open a chat with a user, firebase take 1-3 seconds to load the conversation.

So, I have to insert a progress indicator when firebase is retrieving data on chat opended.

This is the class:

```html
class ChatView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatView({
    Key key,
    @required this.itemId,
    @required this.chatFlag,
    @required this.buyerUserId,
    @required this.sellerUserId,

  }) : super(key: key);

  final String itemId;
  final String chatFlag;
  final String buyerUserId;
  final String sellerUserId;
  // final String isOffer;
  @override
  _ChatViewState createState() => _ChatViewState();
}

enum ChatUserStatus { active, in_active, offline }

class _ChatViewState extends State<ChatView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AnimationController animationController;
  DatabaseReference _messagesRef;
  DatabaseReference _chatRef;
  DatabaseReference _userPresence;
  final bool _anchorToBottom = true;
  FirebaseApp firebaseApp;
  PsValueHolder psValueHolder;
  String sessionId;
  ChatHistoryRepository chatHistoryRepository;
  NotificationRepository notiRepo;
  UserUnreadMessageRepository userUnreadMessageRepository;
  GalleryRepository galleryRepo;
  ProductRepository productRepo;
  GetChatHistoryProvider getChatHistoryProvider;
  UserUnreadMessageProvider userUnreadMessageProvider;
  ChatHistoryListProvider chatHistoryListProvider;
  ItemDetailProvider itemDetailProvider;
  GalleryProvider galleryProvider;
  NotificationProvider notiProvider;
  SyncChatHistoryParameterHolder holder;
  GetChatHistoryParameterHolder getChatHistoryParameterHolder;
  PsResource<ChatHistory> chatHistory;
  String lastTimeStamp;
  int lastAddedDateTimeStamp;
  String status = '';
  String itemId;
  String receiverId;
  String senderId;
  String otherUserId;

  ChatUserStatus isActive;

  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();

  Future<FirebaseApp> configureDatabase() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(

      options: Platform.isIOS
          ? const FirebaseOptions(
              appId: Config.iosGoogleAppId,
              messagingSenderId: Config.iosGcmSenderId,
              databaseURL: Config.iosDatabaseUrl,
              projectId: Config.iosProjectId,
              apiKey: Config.iosApiKey)
          : const FirebaseOptions(
              appId: Config.androidGoogleAppId,
              apiKey: Config.androidApiKey,
              projectId: Config.androidProjectId,
              messagingSenderId: Config.androidGcmSenderId,
              databaseURL: Config.androidDatabaseUrl,
            ),
    );

    return app;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    configureDatabase().then((FirebaseApp app) {
      firebaseApp = app;
    });

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase(app: firebaseApp);
    _messagesRef = database.reference().child('Message');
    _chatRef = database.reference().child('Current_Chat_With');
    _userPresence = database.reference().child('User_Presence');

    if (database != null && database.databaseURL != null) {
      database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
      database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);
    }
    animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: PsConfig.animation_duration, vsync: this);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // user returned to our app
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      _chatRef.child(psValueHolder.loginUserId).remove();
      // app is inactive
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      _chatRef.child(psValueHolder.loginUserId).remove();

      // user is about quit our app temporally
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      // app suspended (not used in iOS)
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    if (mounted) {
      _chatRef.child(psValueHolder.loginUserId).remove();
      _userPresence.child(psValueHolder.loginUserId).remove();
    }

    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    Utils.isReachChatView = false;
  }

  Future<bool> resetUnreadMessageCount(
      ChatHistoryListProvider chatHistoryListProvider,
      PsValueHolder valueHolder,
      UserUnreadMessageProvider userUnreadMessageProvider) async {
    final ResetUnreadMessageParameterHolder resetUnreadMessageParameterHolder =
        ResetUnreadMessageParameterHolder(
            itemId: widget.itemId,
            buyerUserId: widget.buyerUserId,
            sellerUserId: widget.sellerUserId,
            type: widget.chatFlag == PsConst.CHAT_FROM_BUYER
                ? PsConst.CHAT_TO_SELLER
                : PsConst.CHAT_TO_BUYER);

    final dynamic _returnData = await chatHistoryListProvider
        .resetUnreadMessageCount(resetUnreadMessageParameterHolder.toMap());

    if (_returnData == null) {

      if (valueHolder.loginUserId != null && valueHolder.loginUserId != '') {
        final UserUnreadMessageParameterHolder userUnreadMessageHolder =
            UserUnreadMessageParameterHolder(
                userId: valueHolder.loginUserId,
                deviceToken: valueHolder.deviceToken);
        userUnreadMessageProvider
            .userUnreadMessageCount(userUnreadMessageHolder);
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _insertDataToFireBase(
    String id,
    bool isSold,
    bool isUserBought,
    String itemId,
    String message,
    int offerStatus,
    String sendByUserId,
    String sessionId,
    int type,
  ) async {
    final Message messages = Message();
    messages.addedDate = Utils.getTimeStamp();
    messages.id = id;
    messages.isSold = isSold;
    messages.isUserBought = isUserBought;
    messages.itemId = itemId;
    messages.message = message;
    messages.offerStatus = offerStatus;
    messages.sendByUserId = sendByUserId;
    messages.sessionId = sessionId;
    messages.type = type;

    final String newkey = _messagesRef.child(sessionId).push().key;
    messages.id = newkey;

    _messagesRef
        .child(sessionId)
        .child(newkey)
        .set(messages.toInsertMap(messages));

  }

  Future<void> _deleteDataToFireBase(
    String id,
    bool isSold,
    String itemId,
    String message,
    String sendByUserId,
    String sessionId,
  ) async {
    final Message messages = Message();
    messages.addedDate = Utils.getTimeStamp();
    messages.id = id;
    messages.isSold = isSold;
    messages.itemId = itemId;
    messages.message = message;
    messages.sendByUserId = sendByUserId;
    messages.sessionId = sessionId;

    final String key =
        _messagesRef.child(sessionId).child(id).remove().toString();
    messages.id = key;

    _messagesRef
        .child(sessionId)
        .child(key)
        .set(messages.toDeleteMap(messages));
  }

  Future<void> _updateDataToFireBase(
    int addedDate,
    String id,
    bool isSold,
    bool isUserBought,
    String itemId,
    String message,
    int offerStatus,
    String sendByUserId,
    String sessionId,
    int type,
  ) async {
    final Message messages = Message();
    messages.id = id;
    messages.isSold = isSold;
    messages.isUserBought = isUserBought;
    messages.itemId = itemId;
    messages.message = message;
    messages.offerStatus = offerStatus;
    messages.sendByUserId = sendByUserId;
    messages.sessionId = sessionId;
    messages.type = type;
    messages.addedDateTimeStamp = addedDate;

    _messagesRef
        .child(sessionId)
        .child(messages.id)
        .set(messages.toUpdateMap(messages));
  }

  Future<void> _insertSenderAndReceiverToFireBase(
      String sessionId,
      String itemId,
      String receiverId,
      String senderId,
      String userName) async {
    final Chat chat =
        Chat(itemId: itemId, receiverId: receiverId, senderId: senderId);

    _chatRef.child(senderId).set(chat.toMap(chat));

    final ChatUserPresence chatUserPresence =
        ChatUserPresence(userId: senderId, userName: userName);

    _userPresence.child(senderId).set(chatUserPresence.toMap(chatUserPresence));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const Widget _spacingWidget = SizedBox(
      width: PsDimens.space10,
    );
    lastTimeStamp = null;

    psValueHolder = Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(context);
    chatHistoryRepository = Provider.of<ChatHistoryRepository>(context);
    notiRepo = Provider.of<NotificationRepository>(context);
    galleryRepo = Provider.of<GalleryRepository>(context);
    productRepo = Provider.of<ProductRepository>(context);
    userUnreadMessageRepository =
        Provider.of<UserUnreadMessageRepository>(context);
    if (psValueHolder.loginUserId != null) {
      if (psValueHolder.loginUserId == widget.buyerUserId) {
        sessionId =
            Utils.sortingUserId(widget.sellerUserId, widget.buyerUserId);
        otherUserId = widget.sellerUserId;
      } else if (psValueHolder.loginUserId == widget.sellerUserId) {
        sessionId =
            Utils.sortingUserId(widget.buyerUserId, widget.sellerUserId);
        otherUserId = widget.buyerUserId;
      }

      _insertSenderAndReceiverToFireBase(sessionId, widget.itemId, otherUserId,
          psValueHolder.loginUserId, psValueHolder.loginUserName);
    }

    _chatRef.child(otherUserId).onValue.listen((Event event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value == null) {
        if (isActive == null || isActive != ChatUserStatus.offline && mounted) {
          setState(() {
            status = Utils.getString(context, 'chat_view__status_offline');
            isActive = ChatUserStatus.offline;
          });
        }
      } else {
        itemId = event.snapshot.value['itemId'];
        final String _receiverId = event.snapshot.value['receiver_id'];

        if (_receiverId == psValueHolder.loginUserId &&
            itemId == widget.itemId) {
          if (isActive != ChatUserStatus.active && mounted) {
            setState(() {
              status = Utils.getString(context, 'chat_view__status_active');
              isActive = ChatUserStatus.active;
            });
          }
        } else {
          if (isActive != ChatUserStatus.in_active && mounted) {
            setState(() {
              status = Utils.getString(context, 'chat_view__status_inactive');
              isActive = ChatUserStatus.in_active;
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });

    Future<void> checkOfferStatus(ChatHistory chatHistory) async {
      if (chatHistory != null &&
          chatHistory.isOffer == PsConst.ONE &&
          chatHistory.isAccept != PsConst.ONE) {
        await getChatHistoryProvider
            .getChatHistory(getChatHistoryParameterHolder);
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0), // here the desired height
        child: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          systemOverlayStyle:  SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarIconBrightness: Utils.getBrightnessForAppBar(context),
          ),
          iconTheme: Theme.of(context)
              .iconTheme
              .copyWith(color: PsColors.textPrimaryColor),
          title: Text(
            status,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: PsColors.white),
          ),
        backgroundColor: PsColors.mainColor,
        bottomOpacity: 0.0,
        elevation: 0.0)),
      body: PsWidgetWithMultiProvider(
          child: MultiProvider(
              providers: <SingleChildWidget>[
            ChangeNotifierProvider<ItemDetailProvider>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) {
                  itemDetailProvider = ItemDetailProvider(
                      repo: productRepo, psValueHolder: psValueHolder);

                  final String loginUserId =
                      Utils.checkUserLoginId(psValueHolder);
                  itemDetailProvider.loadProduct(widget.itemId, loginUserId);

                  return itemDetailProvider;
                }),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<UserUnreadMessageProvider>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) {
                  userUnreadMessageProvider = UserUnreadMessageProvider(
                      repo: userUnreadMessageRepository);
                  return userUnreadMessageProvider;
                }),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<ChatHistoryListProvider>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) {
                  chatHistoryListProvider =
                      ChatHistoryListProvider(repo: chatHistoryRepository);

                  resetUnreadMessageCount(chatHistoryListProvider,
                      psValueHolder, userUnreadMessageProvider);
                  return chatHistoryListProvider;
                }),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<NotificationProvider>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) {
                  notiProvider = NotificationProvider(
                      repo: notiRepo, psValueHolder: psValueHolder);

                  return notiProvider;
                }),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<GalleryProvider>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) {
                  galleryProvider = GalleryProvider(
                    repo: galleryRepo,
                  );

                  return galleryProvider;
                }),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<GetChatHistoryProvider>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) {
                  getChatHistoryProvider =
                      GetChatHistoryProvider(repo: chatHistoryRepository);
                  getChatHistoryParameterHolder = GetChatHistoryParameterHolder(
                      itemId: widget.itemId,
                      buyerUserId: widget.buyerUserId,
                      sellerUserId: widget.sellerUserId);
                  getChatHistoryProvider
                      .getChatHistory(getChatHistoryParameterHolder);

                  return getChatHistoryProvider;
                }),
          ],
              child: Consumer<ItemDetailProvider>(builder:
                  (BuildContext context, ItemDetailProvider itemDetailProvider,
                      Widget child) {
                if (itemDetailProvider.itemDetail != null &&
                    itemDetailProvider.itemDetail.data != null) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Utils.isLightMode(context)
                        ? Colors.grey[100]
                        : Colors.grey[900],
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            child: Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: ItemInfoWidget(
                                insertDataToFireBase: _insertDataToFireBase,
                                sessionId: sessionId,
                                itemData: itemDetailProvider.itemDetail.data,
                                sendByUserId: psValueHolder.loginUserId ?? '',
                                chatFlag: widget.chatFlag,
                                buyerUserId: widget.buyerUserId,
                                sellerUserId: widget.sellerUserId,
                                chatHistoryProvider: getChatHistoryProvider,
                                isOffer:
                                    (getChatHistoryProvider.chatHistory.data !=
                                                null &&
                                            getChatHistoryProvider
                                                    .chatHistory.data.id !=
                                                '')
                                        ? getChatHistoryProvider
                                            .chatHistory.data.isOffer
                                        : '0',
                                isUserOnline: isActive == ChatUserStatus.active
                                    ? PsConst.ONE
                                    : PsConst.ZERO,
                              )
                            )),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            margin:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: PsDimens.space12),
                            child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                              key: ValueKey<bool>(_anchorToBottom),
                              query: _messagesRef
                                  .child(sessionId)
                                  .orderByChild('itemId')
                                  .equalTo(widget.itemId),
                              reverse: _anchorToBottom,
                              sort: _anchorToBottom
                                  ? (DataSnapshot a, DataSnapshot b) {
                                      return b.value['addedDate']
                                          .toString()
                                          .compareTo(
                                              a.value['addedDate'].toString());
                                    }
                                  : null,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                  DataSnapshot snapshot,
                                  Animation<double> animation,
                                  int index) {
                                print('- - - - - - -  /nIndex : $index');
                                bool isSameDate = false;
                                final Message messages =
                                    Message().fromMap(snapshot.value);

                                final String chatDateString =
                                    Utils.convertTimeStampToDate(
                                        messages.addedDateTimeStamp);
                                if (index == 0 || lastTimeStamp == null) {
                                  lastTimeStamp = chatDateString;
                                  lastAddedDateTimeStamp =
                                      messages.addedDateTimeStamp;
                                }

                                final DateTime msgDate =
                                Utils.getDateOnlyFromTimeStamp(
                                    messages.addedDateTimeStamp);

                                final DateTime lastDate =
                                Utils.getDateOnlyFromTimeStamp(
                                    lastAddedDateTimeStamp);


                                if (lastTimeStamp == chatDateString ||
                                    msgDate.compareTo(lastDate) >= 0) {
                                  isSameDate = true;
                                } else {
                                  isSameDate = false;
                                }

                                final Widget _chatCell =
                                _ChatPageWidget(
                                  buyerUserId: widget.buyerUserId,
                                  sellerUserId: widget.sellerUserId,
                                  chatFlag: widget.chatFlag,
                                  chatHistoryProvider: getChatHistoryProvider,
                                  chatHistoryParameterHolder:
                                      getChatHistoryParameterHolder,
                                  messageObj: messages,
                                  itemDetail:
                                      itemDetailProvider.itemDetail.data,
                                  psValueHolder: psValueHolder,
                                  updateDataToFireBase: _updateDataToFireBase,
                                  insertDataToFireBase: _insertDataToFireBase,
                                  deleteDataToFireBase: _deleteDataToFireBase,
                                  checkOfferStatus: checkOfferStatus,
                                  index: index,
                                  isUserOnline:
                                  isActive == ChatUserStatus.active
                                      ? PsConst.ONE
                                      : PsConst.ZERO,
                                );

                                Widget _dateWidget;
                                if (!isSameDate) {
                                  _dateWidget = Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: PsDimens.space8,
                                        bottom: PsDimens.space8),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        _spacingWidget,
                                        const Expanded(
                                          child: Divider(
                                              height: PsDimens.space1,
                                              color: Colors.black54),
                                        ),
                                        _spacingWidget,
                                        Container(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                              PsDimens.space4),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.black54,
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(
                                                      PsDimens.space8)),
                                          child: Text(
                                            lastTimeStamp,
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .caption
                                                .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        _spacingWidget,
                                        const Expanded(
                                          child: Divider(
                                              height: PsDimens.space1,
                                              color: Colors.black54),
                                        ),
                                        _spacingWidget,
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );

                                  lastTimeStamp = chatDateString;
                                  lastAddedDateTimeStamp =
                                      messages.addedDateTimeStamp;
                                }

                                if (msgDate.compareTo(lastDate) >= 0) {
                                  lastTimeStamp = chatDateString;
                                  lastAddedDateTimeStamp =
                                      messages.addedDateTimeStamp;
                                }

                                return isSameDate
                                    ? _chatCell
                                    : Column(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          _chatCell,
                                          _dateWidget,
                                        ],
                                      );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              }))),
    );
  }
}
```

Can you suggest me a solution?

Flutter version 2.5.3

Comment: when dealing with Futures, use FutureBuilder widget.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a `FutureBuilder` like this (preferably in the main.dart where you initialize Firebase):

```
return FutureBuilder(
          // Initialize FlutterFire:
          future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SomethingWentWrong();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MyAwesomeApp();
        }

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return Loading();
      },
    );
```

For the `Loading();` you can either make your own custom widget or just render a `CircularProgressIndicator()`. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) you can find out how to configure it.

Comment: Can you make the example with my code snippet? Sorry for my newbie question

Comment: You snippet is rather large and I am not sure how your overall project structure looks like, I´d suggest you dive into the [this article](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) and apply it to your project, since you know it best and this will be a way better practice for you to grow as a developer ;)